# Sunrise Sunset time image on current time with javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var doc = document;
clock({
  twentyfour: !!twentyfour,
  padzero: true,
  refresh: 5000,
  success: function(clock) {
    doc.getElementById('time').innerHTML = clock.hour() + ":" + clock.minute();
    document.getElementById('todate').innerHTML = clock.date() + ' ' + translate[current].month[clock.month()] + ' ' + clock.year();
    document.getElementById('today').innerHTML = translate[current].weekday[clock.day()]
  }
});

function mainUpdate(type) {
  doc.getElementById("sunrise").innerHTML = weather.sunriseTimeFormatted;
  doc.getElementById("sunset").innerHTML = weather.sunsetTimeFormatted;

  var dtime = document.getElementById('time');
  var dsunrise = document.getElementById('sunrise');
  var dsunset = document.getElementById('sunset');
  var sunriseI = document.getElementById('sunriseImg');
  var sunsetI = document.getElementById('sunsetImg');

  function sunriseI() {
    if (dtime >= dsunrise) {
      sunriseI.src = 'images/daytwilight.png';
    } else {
      sunriseI.src = 'images/blank.png';
    }
  }

  function sunsetI() {
    if (dtime == dsunset) {
      sunsetI.src = 'images/nighttwilight.png';
    } else {
      sunriseI.src = 'images/blank.png';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<img onload="sunriseI()" id="sunriseImg" src="images/blank.png" />
<img onload="sunsetI()" id="sunsetImg" src="images/blank.png" />
```

not working. I wanna put twilight image on sunrise and sunset time for a while. on current time = sunset or sunrise. Or You can show me different alterrnative.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should format your code properly and explain what should happen, what does happen and any error messages. The *clock* function seems integral to the code but you haven't provided it.

Comment: `dtime >= dsunrise` compares two DOM elements, likely you want to compare their string values, which probably should be converted to numbers or dates first. The same goes for `dtime == dsunset` (which will never be true in the current code).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sunrise = 5;
var sunset = 19;

var sunriseImage = "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/mountain-landscape-background_1284-10559.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg";

var sunsetImage = "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/3d-hazy-mountain-range-against-sunset-sky_1048-10361.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg";

var nightImage = "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/starry-night-sky-background_23-2148058243.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg";

var dayImage = "https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/sky-with-sun-rays_1048-4473.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg";

var initClock = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var minute = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    
    changeTime(hour + " : " + minute + " : " + seconds);
    
    if(hour == sunrise){
      changeImage(sunriseImage);
    }else if(hour == sunsetImage){
      changeImage(sunsetImage);
    }else if(hour > sunset || hour < sunrise){
      changeImage(nightImage);
    }else{
      changeImage(dayImage);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var changeTime = function(time){
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = time;
}

var changeImage = function(img){
      document.getElementById("clock").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+img+"')";
      document.getElementById("clock").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}

initClock();
```

```css
#clock{
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">

</div>
```

Comment: Code–only answers aren't helpful. It doesn't tell the OP what was wrong with their code or how to fix it. You've just provided some code that sort of does what you think the OP code might have done.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if current time is around sunset / sunrise with some offset, and set image element's source based on that.

1. To compare times, First you should convert time `string` to a `Date` object. here is a function for it :

```
function parse_time(str){
  var d_ = new Date();
  d_.setHours(str.split(':')[0]);
  d_.setMinutes(str.split(':')[1]);
  d_.setSeconds(0);
 return d_;
}
```

2. second for checking if a time is around other time with some period, you can use an isAround function like this:

```
function addHours(date, h) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setTime(result.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000));
  return result;
}

function isAround(d1,d2,period){
  return (d1 >= (addHours(d2,-period)) && d1 <= (addHours(d2,period)));
}
```

3. And last, for checking if current time is around sunset or sunrise, use isAround function. And then set source of image element to corresponding image.

```
if (isAround(dtime, dsunrise, 1)) {
  weatherImage.src = "sunrise_img";
}
else if (isAround(dtime, dsunset, 1)) {
  weatherImage.src = 'sunset_img';
} else {
  weatherImage.src = 'empty_img';
}
```

---

And also there was couple of other issues to your file, like using `functions with same names as variables` (`sunriseI`, `sunsetI`), using wrong variables(`sunriseI` in last line), using `onload` events which had wrong scopes and wasn't necessary, using two image elements which was unnecessary, etc.

Here is corrected code with weather check (i tested it and its working):

https://pastebin.com/dKmy8Rcu

Note that: replace `clock1.0.3.2.js` with your `clock.js` version. also i removed `translate` function usages in your code. also i removed `weather`, and replaced it with custom variables for sunset and sunrise.

I removed them because you didn't provided those in your source code, so just change them back if you have that resources.